# Is it possible to user-wide replace default gtk2 widgets with compatible custom ones derived from the original

Tags: widget, gtk, gtk2

(This is an in-theory question, to scratch a personal itch, so I am not interested in "IMHO thats-not-advisable" answers, because this is just something to fix some little things, not to be installed on your machine etc... ;-)

I have made a couple of custom Gtk widgets that extend the base widgets such as GtkFileChooser and GtkNotebook.

(not much, but its something, as of yesterday I knew nothing about gtk or c, so this is more of an in-theory question - however if its not possible there is not much point in me learning any more gtk2)

However I would like to use these widgets in all my gtk2 apps.

Is it possible to over ride the default widgets system-wise without rebuilding the gtk2 libs from source?

It looks like gtk-modules would be the way to go, but the documentation seems sparse, unless my googling is missing something.

The purpose of this, is that the GtkNotebook does not support multiple rows of tabs, however it is used in Geany, Anjuta, Bluefish and numerous other gtk2 based editors. I can recompile geany and Anjuta, and bluefish to use my widget instead, but I'd prefer to swap it out across the board.

Comment: Please consider submitting patches to the actual GTK+ project. That's the most powerful way to add features to all GTK+ widgets on your system, after all. :)

Answer (score 0):

Normally the right solution to reusing widgets between different applications is to create a dynamic library that adds the widgets.

Remember that it's advisable to create real GObject subclasses with a separate GType. Then it's also trivial to add support for say introspection so your widgets can also be used in language bindings etc.